# Get config file from virtualized folder UAC

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-vista, uac

I have inherited a legacy application that used to write its settings to a file under `C:\Program Files\<Company>\<ProgramName>`.

This application pre-dates Windows Vista, and thus does not include a manifest. Thus, when installed on Windows Vista or later, these writes would actually be redirected (virtualized), and the settings file would end up somewhere else -- typically in `C:\Users\<username>AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files(x86)\...` (but if I am correct this depends on the Windows version).

Now I need to update this legacy application, and will include a manifest. The settings file will now need to be stored somewhere else, probably in %APPDATA%. The question is, when the 'updated' version is installed on top of the old one, it would be nice if it can somehow find the previous settings file and copy it over to the new location.

Hence, the question: Is there any way to programatically know where Windows would eventually place a virtualized file, from an application that is **not** virtualized?

Comment: Hi downvoter, what's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where the old application was installed. The user may have installed in `"c:\program files\..."` or `"c:\program files (x86)\"` or some place else.

You have to find the old installation path and remove the drive letter. For example: `"c:\Program Files\Company\Old App"` becomes `"Program Files\Company\Old App"`

Next, append to `VirtualStore` path.

For example:

```
wchar_t *old_application_path = L"Program Files\\Company\\Old App Folder";
wchar_t path[300];

wchar_t *ptr;
if (S_OK == SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &ptr))
{
    wsprintf(path, L"%s\\VirtualStore\\%s", ptr, old_application_path);
    CoTaskMemFree(ptr);
}
```

Note this virtualization is only for protected folders, for example `"c:\Program Files"` which requires admin access for writing data. If the program was installed to unprotected folder, for example `"c:\my programs\"`, then there is no virtualization and the program can write directly to that folder.

Comment: Do you mean that the VirtualStore path is always <FOLDERID_LocalAppData>/VirtualStore ? Is this true for all Windows versions after Windows Vista? (Do you have any reference documentation for this?)

Comment: As far as I know the folder is in the same place for all versions including Windows 7, 8, and 10. I don't know of any documentations in that regard. This is basically a bug fix for very old programs, there may not be any documentation.

Comment: The path to the VirtualStore, at least for Vista and Windows 7, is documented in [Common file and registry virtualization issues in Windows Vista or in Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927387). To detect if the app will have its filesystem and registry access virtualized, you can use `GetTokenInformation(TokenVirtualizationEnabled)`.